# Let $n$ and $k$ be positive integers. Show that $\gcd(n, nk \pm 1) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

This is what I've begun with:

So lets say $x=n,y=nk+1,x,y,n\in\Bbb Z$
Lets say we have a integer, d that divides both x and y. So, $d\vert x$ and $d\vert y$ so if there is a gcd, then d must also divide y-x. $d\vert(y-x)$ but we said $x=n,y=nk+1$. Then, $d\vert(nk+1-n)$=$d\vert (n(k-1)+1)$.
But I have no idea if I'm heading in the right direction? Any tips?

Comment: Hint: $d | n $ implies that $d | nk$

Comment: You can repeat your argument to obtain $d\mid (n(k-2)+1)$, …, $d\mid (n\cdot 0+1)$, so $d$ is a divisor of $1$. Or immediately use that $d\mid n$ implies $d\mid nk$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p\mid n$ and $p\mid nk+1$. Then $n=pq$ and $nk+1=pr$ for some $q,r\in\mathbb Z$. Therefore \begin{align*}
nk+1=kpq+1=pr&\implies p(r-kq)=1\\
&\implies p\mid 1.
\end{align*}

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.